# Some questions about setting up Amazon S3 with Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I'm trying to setup Amazon S3 hosting with my Ruby on Rails 3 app, which is hosted on Heroku. After reading [these instructions](http://docs.heroku.com/s3#ruby-plugins) in the Heroku docs, I'm trying to use the aws-s3 gem.

The [instructions](http://docs.heroku.com/s3#ruby-plugins) say to put the S3 account details in `config/amazon_s3.yml`, but the [aws-s3 Github page](https://github.com/marcel/aws-s3) says you create a connection like this:

```
AWS::S3::Base.establish_connection!(
    :access_key_id     => 'abc', 
    :secret_access_key => '123'
)
```

Why is the connection created by providing the details if they're already provided in the config file? Is that not the correct way to establish a connection? Do I have to establish a connection for each user everytime an upload is about to occur, or is a connection established for the application as a whole?

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're reading documentation for different gems. If you use Attachment-Fu or Paperclip, they'll manage S3 connection internally and you need to only provide credentials.  If you access S3 directly (through aws-s3 gem), you'll need to establish connection explicitly.

Comment: Whoops, that's embarrassing. Thanks for your help.